# Custom UITableViewCell being temporarily clipped

Tags: objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I have a custom UITableViewCell on my UITableView.

I am working with AutoLayout and iOS7.

The height of the cell seems to be more than I need (I hardcoded it just to be sure that it was not the problem).

The cell contains some labels and images, that appear initially clipped:

[image: First screen]

But after I scroll a bit, they suddenly appear.

They also appear if I select the row.

[image: Second picture]

It's really really weird. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try to use bounds instead of frame where it is appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean? I am not manually setting the frames. I am using autolayout.

Comment: Show your constraints.

Comment: I removed all constraints just to be sure that they were not breaking the view